# How to verify that the Unofficial Patch was installed for Vampires Bloodlines?

Tags: mods, vampire-the-masquerade-bloodlines

I have ran the setup of the [Unofficial Patch](http://www.patches-scrolls.de/patch/4647), as of this writing 9.2. How do I verify it got installed before starting a new game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the main menu, select option and navigate to gameplay. There it should read:

"Unofficial Patch 9.2".